# How to log actual effort of a task in TFS

Tags: tfs

Recently came across "Remaining Work" option in TFS, got no clue what it stands for, is it the time in hours that i am supposed to define against a task.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you talking about? You have this tagged as, 3 different versions of TFS, plus the general TFS tag, plus a totally irrelevant TFSbuild tag.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better suited for Programmers.SE

Comment: @LaurentS.this question would be off-topic at programmers.se.  Please read the posting guidelines there before recommending it again.

Answer (score 1):

Remaining work is the number of hours you have left to complete a task. If something is a 4 hr task and at the end of a day you have managed to complete 1hrs work, you would update it to 3hrs remaining. You can update the remaining work as often as you like. You could just 0 it when there is no more work, or every time there is 1hr's less work remaining - or somewhere in between.

From this value, TFS can create a burndown graph of remaining work in an iteration.

There are fields for Original Estimate and Actual Work you can use if you need to track estimates and how long things took.

Answer (score 0):

Remaining Work field can actually show if the original estimate has changed since you started working on a task.